# jq - Select Random object from each array and only return certain values in each object of filtered arrays

Tags: json, bash, jq

Overall Goals:

- I take user input, as country and/or city variables, then use those variables to filter down the JSON data to only the relays that meet the users choice. (Probably do some regex in JQ when selecting with the user input variables, to make sure someone can input `New York` and it would match `New York, NY`)
- I then want to select a random relay in the relay array, or 1 random relay in each cities relay array, which is where I am getting stuck.
- After I get a random relay in that/each array, I want to print certain values based on the key (i.e. ipvr_addr_in and public_key), in a csv format (for now).
- If there are multiple relays at this point, I would iterate through them to find the lowest latency, sort the list, choose the lowest and pass that IP,key pair on to the final configuration.

Originally, I thought I'd just grab the first object in the array and use that:

```
country_choice=UK
city_choice=London
if [[ -z "$city_choice" ]]; then
    jq --arg country_choice "$country_choice" -r '.countries[] | select(.name==$country_choice) | .cities[] | .relays[:1] | .ipv4_addr_in+","+.public_key' testdata.json
else
    jq --arg country_choice "$country_choice" --arg city_choice "$city_choice" -r '.countries[] | select(.name==$country_choice) | .cities[] | select(.name==$city_choice) | .relays[:1] | .ipv4_addr_in+","+.public_key' testdata.json
fi
```

But that resulted in the JQ error: `Cannot index array with string "public_key"`

I am still very new to JQ and JSONs, so I am unfamiliar with why I can't print out specific values after filtering down to a specific object of several arrays.

Can anyone help me out here? I can't seem to find anything online about "selecting random" in jq.

Also any help with some of my other overall goals would be very much appreciated, I'm no coding guru.

An abridged test dataset (testdata.json):

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "UK",
      "code": "gb",
      "cities": [
        {
          "name": "London",
          "code": "lon",
          "relays": [
            {
              "hostname": "gb4-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "141.98.252.130",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a03:1b20:7:f011::a01f",
              "public_key": "IJJe0TQtuQOyemL4IZn6oHEsMKSPqOuLfD5HoAWEPTY="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "gb5-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "141.98.252.222",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a03:1b20:7:f011::a02f",
              "public_key": "J57ba81Q8bigy9RXBXvl0DgABTrbl81nb37GuX50gnY="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "gb-lon-wg-101",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "146.70.119.66",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2001:ac8:31:f007::a39f",
              "public_key": "MPZX0ZQtB5r1pmcvIcsAt1AMvenios2ICBz9rjbN/l4="
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Manchester",
          "code": "mnc",
          "relays": [
            {
              "hostname": "gb45-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "146.70.133.34",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2001:ac8:8b:2b::a45f",
              "public_key": "v+dOPx0FM8lGCjJ7m/7miWy67PGuazYYzvJoeMb97n4="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "gb46-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "146.70.133.66",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2001:ac8:8b:2c::a46f",
              "public_key": "2bciRobW0TPtjrZ2teilr+7PjyiBMUGfixvAKOE52Xo="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "gb-mnc-wg-001",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "146.70.133.98",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2001:ac8:8b:2d::a47f",
              "public_key": "Q2khJLbTSFxmppPGHgq2HdxMQx7CczPZCgVpYZMoNnM="
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "USA",
      "code": "us",
      "cities": [
        {
          "name": "New York, NY",
          "code": "nyc",
          "relays": [
            {
              "hostname": "us97-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "86.106.143.210",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a0d:5600:24:a94::a97f",
              "public_key": "5fzEFqyRqc6qa1QPngIBK1gmWc0ex1Bpot/f6RqZPmc="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "us98-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "86.106.143.223",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a0d:5600:24:a95::a98f",
              "public_key": "bo50ppMvVlNG4S6zqgd/J5l1Ce7Og89u+wR10OvJrQ4="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "us99-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "86.106.143.236",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a0d:5600:24:a96::a99f",
              "public_key": "EPLh6pVel06dND8cE4Prix9GP4hGLYNhQhn5mSN2yzM="
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Seattle, WA",
          "code": "sea",
          "relays": [
            {
              "hostname": "us274-wireguard",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "138.199.43.78",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a02:6ea0:d80b:2::b74f",
              "public_key": "ujasJmDuU0t4y6JmBLrdDxakKuaHvPRupRDfyywSWyw="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "us-sea-wg-001",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "138.199.43.91",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a02:6ea0:d80b:3::b75f",
              "public_key": "bZQF7VRDRK/JUJ8L6EFzF/zRw2tsqMRk6FesGtTgsC0="
            },
            {
              "hostname": "us-sea-wg-003",
              "ipv4_addr_in": "138.199.43.65",
              "ipv6_addr_in": "2a02:6ea0:d80b:1::b73f",
              "public_key": "4ke8ZSsroiI6Sp23OBbMAU6yQmdF3xU2N8CyzQXE/Qw="
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Basic pseudo-random number generator in jq: https://github.com/fadado/JBOL/blob/master/fadado.github.io/math/chance.jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.relays[1:]` gives you an array of all but the first item. Use `.relays[0]` instead to get only the first item:

```bash
.countries[] | select(.name==$country_choice)
| .cities[] | select(.name==$city_choice)
| .relays[0] | .ipv4_addr_in+","+.public_key
```

```
141.98.252.130,IJJe0TQtuQOyemL4IZn6oHEsMKSPqOuLfD5HoAWEPTY=
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/F6AEkX0X1xq)

---

As for a random value, jq does not have a random number generator. You could, however, (poorly) emulate one based on the current time using `now`, or import one generated outside using `--arg` or `--argjson`.

---

Here's one very simple jq-only implementation of your script importing the `$RANDOM` variable from `bash`, which "expands to a random integer between 0 and 32767" (so make sure your arrays are not longer than that):

```bash
country_choice=UK    # setting the country
city_choice=         # omitting the city

jq --arg country_choice "$country_choice" --argjson country_random $RANDOM \
  --arg city_choice "$city_choice" --argjson city_random $RANDOM \
  --argjson relay_random $RANDOM -r \
  '
    .countries
    | if $country_choice == ""
      then .[$country_random % length]
      else .[] | select(.name == $country_choice) end
    
    | .cities
    | if $city_choice == ""
      then .[$city_random % length]
      else .[] | select(.name == $city_choice) end
    
    | .relays | .[$relay_random % length]
    | .ipv4_addr_in + "," + .public_key
  '
```

```
146.70.133.98,Q2khJLbTSFxmppPGHgq2HdxMQx7CczPZCgVpYZMoNnM=
```

[Demo (with faked random numbers)](https://jqplay.org/s/Otqu8Q_mCQ1)

Comment: I thought I might have to do it elsewhere. If I generate a random number for ```.relays[X]```, and the number happens to be higher than the number of objects in the array, what would happen? My real data set has anywhere from a couple of relays to over a dozen.

Comment: @ehammer Typically you'd use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` on the `length` of the array. Primitive (=losing some randomness) example: `jq --argjson r $RANDOM '… | .relays | .[$r % length] | …'`

Comment: It seems to be working pretty well, I have some issues with the actual random number I am generating, currently using this command: ```date +%s%N | cut -b10-19```. But I frequently run into the error: ```string ("22652") and number (3) cannot be divided (remainder)```. What would you use to generate the initial random number?

Comment: @ehammer You are most probably importing your "number" as a string using `--arg` instead of `--argjson`. Apart from that, if you base your generator on time, you can avoid imports completely and source it from `now`.

Comment: Sorry if this is hijacking my own post, but do you know of a way to search for a string and show a key of the arrays parent object? Specifically, I am looking for a way to search the entire JSON (of my original post) for a specific value of ```ipv4_addr_in``` and find the city name that the IP resides under. I can't seem to get the wording quite right on a google search to find a way to do this with jq.

Comment: @ehammer That's way simpler: provide the value using `--arg`, traverse the document collecting values to be output into variables, filter each branch using `select`, and format your output based on the variables collected: `jq -r --arg query "141.98.252.222" '.countries[] | .name as $country | .cities[] | .name as $city | .relays[] | select(.ipv4_addr_in == $query) | $country + "/" + $city'` will print `UK/London`. Here's a [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UfvTXK8prMQ) which sets the `$query` in the code as there is no option for `--arg` on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question envisions requiring several or an *a priori* unknown number of random values, the following illustration may be of interest.

```
< /dev/urandom tr -cd '0-9' | fold -w 1 | jq -MRcnr '

# Output: a prn in range(0;$n) where $n is `.`
def prn:
  if . == 1 then 0
  else . as $n
  | ([1, (($n-1)|tostring|length)]|max) as $w
  | [limit($w; inputs)] | join("") | tonumber
  | if . < $n then . else ($n | prn) end
  end;


# An illustration - 10 selections at random with replacement
[range(0;10) | ["a", "b", "c"] | .[length|prn]]
'
```

Notice that STDIN is used for the entropy source; file inputs would have to be handled using command-line options such as `--rawfile` or `--slurpfile`.

In fact, if one requires an `a priori` unknown number of random values, then there really isn't any other practical choice when using the current version of jq.